# I want to create bottom sheet dialog like this image below in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Please help me!!!
I m new in flutter, i want to create like this in my flutter app on button click.

[image]

Comment: Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_action_sheet

Answer (score 2):

You can use cupertino bottom modal to achieve something like that. See below code for implementation:

```
void show() {
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext cont) {
          return CupertinoActionSheet(
            actions: [
              CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Camera');
                },
                child: Text('Use Camera'),
              ),
              CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Upload files');
                },
                child: Text('Upload from files'),
              ),
              CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Dropbox');
                },
                child: Text('Upload from DropBox'),
              )
            ],
            cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(cont).pop;
              },
              child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Call the show function with the press of any button. You will see something like this.

[image]

If you don't want the divider between actions you have to create your own custom popup.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext cntx) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.camera),
              title: Text("Camera"),
              onTap: () async {
          
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.image),
              title:  Text("Files")),
              onTap: () async {
              },
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              color: prefix0.appBackgroundColcor,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Cancel",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      });
```